# Using Stacked Brackets in R

Tags: r, list, brackets

I currently have the following list:

```
My_List <- list(DF, Hair, Names, Numbers)
```

DF is a dataframe, the rest are vectors.
I want to take the third value from the hair vector.

The first way I figured to do this was the following:

```
My_List[4[3]]
```

But this unfortunately does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My_List[[2]][3] should work, that would pull the 2 object in my list (Hair) and its 3rd component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this little example. Indexing in lists should be done with `[[]]` to identify the element in the list, and then other `[[]]` to extract some value based on position. Here the code:

```
#Code
Mylist <- list(iris,v1=c(1:4),v2=c(1:5),v3=c(1:9))
```

Now indexing in order to extract third element from second object `v1` in `Mylist`:

```
#Code 2
Mylist[[2]][[3]]
```

Output:

```
Mylist[[2]][[3]]
[1] 3
```